# should a high performance trading engine save to DB synchronously?

Tags: database, performance, rabbitmq, zeromq, trading

For a high performance trading engine, it matches/handles one order at a time, should it save the order and other critical info to DB before it moves on to the next one?

or can I use a separate thread to save to DB asynchronously?

if asynchronously, I can use zeromq to send a msg containing the critical info to DB server, however, if this crashes, order info are lost.

instead if I use a rabbitmq, which persist message to disk, is it safe enough?

Comment: You need to be very careful about asynchronous operations; people get upset if you report that their trade succeeded but the system crashes before that is recorded in the database. Most of the time, it won't be a problem; when it matters, it really matters.  If RabbitMQ provides you with sufficient guarantees — when it tells you that the message was received, it guarantees to deliver it — then it will probably be OK.  Something has to make sure that no trades are lost.

Comment: I would not use zeromq for anything related to financial transactions; use it only for displaying information, like ticker or trade blotter, not for persisting critical information; use traditional messaging for that (RabbitMq, ActiveMq, or commercial like Sonic, etc)

Comment: Sure, it's not for transaction or persistence. It does have a good application in finance application for its high speed and throughput. I used it for user order request, it has a reliable request/reply pattern

Comment: I think you need to define "high performance" and justify why saving to a disk would constitute "low performance" - using properly-designed SSD storage platforms, there is virtually no difference between a transaction executed in memory only vs one saved to the disk.

Comment: I am asking for guide on best software design practice or performance/reliability leverage. an SSD certainly helps in any situation. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question opens a whole Pandorra Box full of very important issues and questions.

**ZeroMQ** is used in this industry right because it is a smart, devillish fast & has both a minimalistic foot-print & low overheads, **nevertheless** the solution you ask about is not based on a single layer of technology or on a trivial Yes/No answer.

Whatever promises the IT industry gives -- be it for SSD, advanced SSD, 3D-SSD and similar innovations, the core responsibility is on your end-to-end system architecture feasibility, not on a technology element. Suppose any element may and will fail. There is no "Ehm, Houston, we have a problem" call in the Markets, the less in HFT.

### Next steps

1. Be exact - state quantitative and measurable requirements
2. Design against requirements ( not opinions, whatever marketing visibility these may have )
3. Test both against peak and sustained performance thresholds
4. Do not compromise in Business Disaster Recovery Measures testing ( chained worst-case-s + lottery of surprises )
5. Be methodical and persistent, compromises are rather expensive ( if not fatal )

If you take just the last 4 decades of the use of the high performance computation in the Finance Markets, there have been met the principal cornerstones for achieving both the high-performance & fault-resillience. Along this path, there were seen also mis-concepts and devastating effects of poor design and lack of error-isolation practices -- just take the Knights HFT crash ( well, rather hours of HFT still-injecting faulty XTO-instructions ) to have a view of the $ize$ an "impact crater" in thi$ indu$try may have, if the cra$h happen$ to materiali$e.

### High performance trading engine

Let's assume you state for your system both the scope and performance envelopes:

```
[SCOPE]------------------------------------------------------------
Forex Majors instruments   { EURUSD, GBPUSD, <list-all-that-applicable> }
Forex Exotic instruments   { <list-all-that-applicable> }
Precious Metals            { XAUUSD, XAGUSD, <list-all-that-applicable> }
Commodities                { <list-all-that-applicable> }
US-stocks                  { AAPL, GOOG, XOM, <list-all-that-applicable> }
Euro-stocks                { <list-all-that-applicable> }
*-stocks                   { <list-all-that-applicable> }
US-indices                 { <list-all-that-applicable> }
Euro-indices               { FTSE, CAC, DAX, AMS, <list-all-that-applicable> }
*-indices                  { <list-all-that-applicable> }
Futures                    { <list-all-that-applicable> }
Options                    { <list-all-that-applicable> }
Binary Options             { <list-all-that-applicable> }
Options on Futures         { <list-all-that-applicable> }
Options on Indices         { <list-all-that-applicable> }
BT*-based instruments      { <list-all-that-applicable> }
```

In a similar structure, state for design evaluations the real-time operations performance constraints, with both sustained & peak values in [msec]

```
[PERFORMANCE]------------------------------------------------------
System requirement for a number of Market Events per msec per segment
System requirement for a number of PriceFeed Quotes per msec per segment
System requirement for a number of OrderProcessing Events per msec per segment
```

**This gives you the first, elementary, metrics for constraining your system Real-Time-Operations design.** I.e. what overhead / latency limits you have to design against, and thus what tools and what measures you have time in [usec]-s to incorporate in any stage of the pipeline so as to still guarantee the system real-time stability and robustness thresholds.

### Order matching/handling one at a time?

This is not a question. This is a given externality.

[*Order*] matching is typically given by the **Market Regulatory Body** ( if not designing for a Dark Pool & other non-public quasi-market(s) ) so as to meet a Fair Market principle. Order handling is sub-ordinated to your regulatory & audit-supervision duties. Both of these are not a field for a free will of the system design.

### Should it save?

The [*Order*] and other critical info to DB before it moves on to the next one or can I use a separate thread to save to DB asynchronously? .. is answered more by the system requirements from audit/supervisory bodies than from the opinion of the technical committee.

### If this crashes?

If your system architecture design permits, it can crash. Then you need measures for post-crash re-instating

If your system architecture design requires to develop system that does not crash, this will become an empty issue. Application online-mirroring + hot-standby shading with N+1, (N+1)+1 or (N+M)+1 redundancy models are achievable, so that individual crashes are properly isolated.

### Is it safe enough?

Depends on your Business Disaster Recovery Planning & Business Continuity Measures. Testing is inevitable.

**Remember the famous Nobelist Dick Feynman's finger pointing into the middle of the Nuke Plant blueprints ...**

Answer (score 1):

There are too many sides to this question, but here are a few things to consider...

What is the likelihood of crashes and the consequences of losing "critical" data in the event of a crash? This is really a business question (as opposed to technology). In many cases, the cost-benefit supports the idea that it is ok to lose data and just pay the price of dealing with it every time it happens. In the early days, it was common for brokers to guarantee "order executing in X or your transaction cost back", but not even measure it. If you complained, they simply issued a refund.

Once you know what data must absolutely be persisted, a high performance system will need to find the fastest way to do so. There are many nuances here as well? What degree of "safety" do you need?

- In-Process memory? (data disappears if the process crashes)
- Out-of-process memory (data disappears if the "persist" process also crashes)?
- OS disk buffer, but still not disk (data disappears if OS crashes as well)?
- Physical disk (data disappears if disk itself, or entire server, "vanishes")?

Nobody can tell you what each HFT company is doing in this regard (they are too secretive). In banks, brokers and so on, it is common to persist the data to a fast disk in the simplest and fastest format possible (for example, FIX messages would be simply dumped into binary files as received) before the next message is processed (in many cases without regard to whether the data is physically written to disk, or still in an OS buffer). This gives you a piece of mind in case of a crash of the application. Further processing will then be done asynchronously (like writing to a database so the data can be queried easily, or checking risk limits and so on).